# Al hacer click en un checkbox jquery solo funciona si hay un alert

Tags: jquery

Tengo una lista de checkbox, el usuario selecciona los de su preferencia y despues presiona un botón y se guardan.

```
$('#GuardarPermisos').on('click', function () {
   Guardar();
}
```

Esto lo quiero cambiar a que  cada vez que dan click en un checkbox se guarde la selección sin necesidad de presionar el botón.

Los checkbox generados tienen una clase, con la cual hago lo siguiente:

```
$('.tiposas').on('click', function () {
    alert('a');
});`
```

Cada que se da click en uno esto debe realizar una acción, pero no funciona a menos que ponga un alert antes del evento.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   alert('con este alert si funciona')';
   $('.tiposas').on('click', function () {
   alert('a');
   });
});
```

NO se que estoy haciendo mal, espero me puedan ayudar

Gracias.

Comment: alert('con este alert si funciona')'; tiene una comilla de mas, puedes dar clic derecho sobre el navegador y ver en consola el error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En ciertas ocaciones cuando le hablas directo a los selectores no funciona, yo en lo particular le hablo al DOM para forzar a buscar donde quiera que esté te dejo un ejemplo

```js
//Es lo mismo que document.ready, pero mas cordo
$(function(){

//Aquí es donde te digo que le hablo al document, le ligo el evento, le digo que selectores y le paso lo que quiero que haga
$( document ).on( 'click', '.foo', function(){
let val = $(this).val();
  //Revisa en que status está el checkbox y controlalo según lo //desees
  if( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ){
    alert( 'Guardando información de '+ val +'...' );
  }
  
  else{
    alert( 'Desguardando información de ' + val + '...' );
  }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Foo<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Foo">
Bar<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Bar">
Poo<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Poo">
Nee<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Nee">
Lol<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Lol">
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Mil gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

hay varios metodos para hacer lo que quieres y para ello nececitas verificar que los checkbox esten seleccionados aqui un ejemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$( '.mycheckbox' ).on( 'click', function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        // Hacer algo si el checkbox ha sido seleccionado
        alert("El checkbox con valor " + $(this).val() + " ha sido seleccionado");
    } else {
        // Hacer algo si el checkbox ha sido deseleccionado
        alert("El checkbox con valor " + $(this).val() + " ha sido deseleccionado");
    }
});
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

Quita una comilla en la linea donde esta el `alert.`

Después de cerrar el último paréntesis, tu código debería quedar algo como esto retirando el `alert`:

```html
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.tiposas').on('click', function () {
      alert('a');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentó Rene, tienes una comilla de más, tu código debería estar así:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   alert('con este alert si funciona');
   $('.tiposas').on('click', function () {
   alert('a');
   });
});
```

---

Para guardar al pulsar el checkbox compruebas si está `checked`

```js
$(".check").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    alert('Guardado');
    //Aquí colocas tu función guardar();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' class='check'>Checkbox 1</input>
<input type='checkbox' class='check'>Checkbox 2</input>
<input type='checkbox' class='check'>Checkbox 3</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa usando el evento `change` y un poco de ES6

```js
let laLista = [];

let ponerElemento = (v) => {
  laLista.push(v);
}
let borraElemento = (v) => {
  laLista = laLista.filter(e => e !== v);
}
/* 
// forma tradicional
let borraElemento = (v) => {
  let i = laLista.indexOf(v);
  if (i > -1) {
    laLista.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
//*/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

  [...checkboxes].forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('change', (ev) => {
      if (ev.target.checked) {
        ponerElemento(ev.target.value);
        consolog(ev.target.value, 'checked', "Lista:", laLista)
      } else {
        borraElemento(ev.target.value);
        consolog(ev.target.value, 'not checked', "Lista:", laLista)
      }
    })
  })

});


// para que el log no tape las cosas
var consolog = function(...cosas) {
  var logs = document.getElementById('logs');
  cosas.forEach((t) => {
    logs.innerHTML += t + " ";
  });
  logs.innerHTML += "\n";
  logs.scrollTop = logs.scrollHeight;

};
```

```css
#logs {
  height: 11em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-width: 50vw;
  background: #fafafa;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
Foo
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Foo">
<br> Bar
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Bar">
<br> Poo
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Poo">
<br> Nee
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Nee">
<br> Lol
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" value="Lol">

<PRE id="logs"></PRE>
```